# Which preposition is acceptable?

Tags: prepositions

I'm confused with the use of prepositions in the following setence. Which preposition is acceptable?

> He was bent on/for music and dancing.

Comment: to be bent on something: to want to only do that. It's an idiom.

Answer (score 1):

*Bent on X* is an idiom that means "really wanting to X" or "really intending to X".  This is an example of an idiom where the meanings of the individual words do not add up to the final meaning.

*Bent for X* would have its literal meaning and would be strange.

Comment: It is not an idiom but a figurative usage.  To be **bent** means to be inclined from a straight line, tending in a particular direction, which  in **to be bent on X** becomes, figuratively, as having a leaning or bias,  a strong proclivity, desire, or fixation to do X.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bent-on), the correct term is **bent on**, which means

> to be very determined to do something

You can suggest that somebody is even more determined to do something, particularly something potentially damaging, by saying **hell bent on**. There is another expression **[Hell for leather](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hell-for-leather)**, and somehow these two have been mixed up to give **hell bent for leather** and a few variants of it.

This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bent%20on%2C%20bent%20for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbent%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbent%20for%3B%2Cc0) shows that **bent on** is the main usage but **bent for** does occur occasionally, particularly in a **hell bent for** type phrase.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing two different idioms.

There's "to have a bent for", which means to be keen on or skilled at a particular discipline.

"Linda has a bent for carpentry," expresses the idea that Linda is a keen (and probably skilled) carpenter.

While "Faroukh is bent on getting top marks in the class in maths," conveys that Faroukh is determined to be top of his class in his maths exams.

I suppose "he's hell bent for [a particular destination]" is possible too, but it sounds a little unnatural to me ... unless, that is, the reference is directly geographical.

It also (imo) needs the "hell" modifier.